# How to right translate "if it is to keep its edge"

Tags: american-english

Whole phrase is: "A mind needs books like a sword needs a whetstone, if it is to keep its edge".

How right understand meaning of this part of phrase: "**if it is to** keep its edge"?

For russians:
Я понимаю, что перевод на русский это "чтобы сохранить свою остроту", но почему не дословно "если есть, то сохранить свою остроту"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it is an expression - they are sometimes formed to sound great on the cost of their exact meaning.

So yes, you "should" say:

> "A mind needs books like a sword needs a whetstone, if it is to keep its edge ***sharp***".

Comment: Thank you for answer. I don't understand part "if it is to". What is it mean?

Comment: *It* being the sword. So a sword needs a whetstone (which you use to sharpen knifes/swords back in the day), if the sword wants to keep its sharp edges. If the owner of the sword does not have a whetstone, he cannot sharpen the edges of the sword.